# JMX - monitor complex attribute of MBean

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I have a simple third party object - a DTO with about 10+ public fields only (it get filled as an atomic operation). I would like to be able to monitor it in JConsole without writing a lot of boilerplate code.

I tried to:

- Use MXBean - got an exception (NotCompliantMBeanException)
- Convert the DTO to String using reflection-based utility library like apache.common.lang3.ReflectionToStringBuilder - works, but does not look good since JConsole does not support multi-line strings well, plus it is not efficient.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted you failing MXBean code. Typically, you would just need to define a **DTOMXBean** interface, make the DTO implement it and then register the DTO. (It sounds like a weird lifecycle for a DTO since they're usually fairly transient, but that's a topic for a different question).

Keep in mind that the MXBean attributes should not return values of types not defined in [javax.management.openmbean.OpenType.ALLOWED_CLASSNAMES_LIST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/OpenType.html#ALLOWED_CLASSNAMES_LIST), otherwise you will get a NonCompliant exception. If you must expose types that cannot be represented as one of those types, you will need to define new composite types to expose them as.

Comment: My MXBean is not the DTO but a container class. For example: I monitor an instance of the class "MyService". MyService contains a complex field (the DTO) of type "MemoryUsage" which is exposed via MyServiceMXBean interface. MemoryUsage has few public integer fields. 
I am not able to show MemoryUsage inner fields in JConsole.